# Hyperlink on an image to open webpage in new tab

Tags: hyperlink, jekyll

How do I attach a hyperlink to an image to open in a new window in Jekyll.

In HTML it would read something like

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com/">
  <img alt="Google Logo" src="https://www.google.com/images/logo.png" width=150" height="70" target="_blank">
</a>
```

What code would I use in Jekyll to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Since Jekyll is using Kramdown as Markdown renderer, you can use the [span IAL](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#span-ials) to add any attribute to a link.

> Additional link attributes can be added by using a [span IAL](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#span-ials) after the inline link, for example:
>
> ```
> This is a [link](http://example.com){:hreflang="de"}
> ```

<sup>*Source: https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#inline-links*</sup>

So in your case you can go with

```
[![Google Logo](https://www.google.com/images/logo.png)](https://www.google.com/){:target="_blank"}
```

Which indeed renders as

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">
  <img src="https://www.google.com/images/logo.png" alt="Google Logo">
</a>
```